# PostrgreSQL privileges granting

Tags: postgresql

Given I am a root user X. I have users A and B.

How do I GRANT user A to enable him granting user B to execute a specific set of functions?

For example we have user A that owns database_1. User A creates some stored functions on this DB (say, `function_a` and `function_b`). User A should be able grant execution of that functions to user B, and only to him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, an object's owner has ALL PRIVILEGES on that object, but I don't recall specifically whether those privileges extend to allowing a normal (non-super) user to `GRANT` permissions on that object to other users.

In any case, you should be able to give that ability to a user by appending the `WITH GRANT OPTION` clause to a `GRANT` statement. (I refer you to [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-grant.html) for full details.)

For example, in your hypothetical scenario, as superuser `X`, you could do something like this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES  ON DATABASE database_1  TO A  WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

User `A` would then have the power to `GRANT` permissions on objects in `database_1` to other users. Continuing the hypothetical example, user `A` could give specific permissions to user `B`, like this:

```
GRANT EXECUTE  ON FUNCTION function_a(), function_b()  TO B;
```